# Ajax request from Web Application to a local TCP Listener

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, iis, network-programming

In advance, sorry for the newbie questions but I need to get some clarity.

I am working on a TCP listener using c# and .net core.
The purpose of this project is to create a server that listens for JSON data, processes it and then sends it to a local printer.
The JSON data is sent from a web application using JavaScript (Ajax) on the same local network.

Everything works fine when the Ajax call is made from a simple html/js page, but not when it is embedded in my web application (asp net core mvc).

The data received is completely corrupted (or encrypted?).
I think the problem is that IIS uses a "local" ssl certificate and my TCP listener server does not have one.
So the transferred data is encrypted and cannot be understood by the server.
I tried to set the "crossdomain" property of my ajax to true, but with no result.

Can you confirm that the ssl certificate could be the cause of the problem?

The server was made using the nugget package "SimpleTCP", what would you advise me to use instead for this type of project?

I have read about SslStream, but before I rewrite the server I would like to be sure what I am doing...

Does the certificate I have to use on my server have to be the same as the one used by IIS? (I guess so if I want to decrypt the data...)

Thanks in advance for your time and interest!

Edit :

Here is the Ajax call, from the web application.

```
let dataToSend = [
    {label : "Soft", price : 2, quantity : 1},
    {label : "Beer", price : 4, quantity : 2},
    {label : "Coffee", price : 2, quantity : 1}
];

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://192.168.1.53:8910',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

And here is the event on the tcp listener which is triggered when data is received:

```
private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
{
    //this.Console is a textbox
    this.Console.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
    {
        int indexDelimiter = e.MessageString.IndexOf(this.JsonResponseDelimiter);

        if(indexDelimiter < 0)
        {
            this.Log("\r\nNo Json data found...");
            return;
        }

        string response = e.MessageString.Substring(indexDelimiter);
        this.Log(response);

        try
        {
            List<TicketLineDTO> ticketLineDTOs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TicketLineDTO>>(response);

            e.ReplyLine("Message correctly transfered.");

            if (ticketLineDTOs != null && ticketLineDTOs.Count > 0)
            {
                this.PrintReceivedData(ticketLineDTOs);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Log("\r\nWrong data... " + ex.Message);
        }               

    });
}
```

And here is the content of e.MessageString :

> "\u0016\u0003\u0001\u0002\0\u0001\0\u0001�\u0003\u0003)��\r1�`A�NT�*g�~2Z�j\t\u0005�)�N���렜 v�xZ#�E\v;D�!}c\u0003�x#O\u0018\u0016���#x��\t%\0 ��\u0013\u0001\u0013\u0002\u0013\u0003�+�/�,�0̨̩�\u0013�\u0014\0�\0�\0/\05\u0001\0\u0001���\0\0\0\u0017\0\0�\u0001\0\u0001\0\0\n\0\n\0\bJJ\0\u001d\0\u0017\0\u0018\0\v\0\u0002\u0001\0\0#\0\0\0\u0010\0\u000e\0\f\u0002h2\bhttp/1.1\0\u0005\0\u0005\u0001\0\0\0\0\0\r\0\u0012\0\u0010\u0004\u0003\b\u0004\u0004\u0001\u0005\u0003\b\u0005\u0005\u0001\b\u0006\u0006\u0001\0\u0012\0\0\03\0+\0)JJ\0\u0001\0\0\u001d\0 <۠xv��\u0002K`L\0\u0006?a�����.\u000f�\u001b��_(B\u0005\u000f\0-\0\u0002\u0001\u0001\0+\0\a\u0006::\u0003\u0004\u0003\u0003\0\u001b\0\u0003\u0002\0\u0002Di\0\u0005\0\u0003\u0002h2��\0\u0001\0\0\u0015\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

Comment: Why are you writing a TcpListener?  Why not just create an endpoint on your asp net core mvc wep site?

Comment: Seems like this would be before the handshake so it could just be compression and not encryption.  Trying un-gzipping data.

Comment: @Neil: Because my web application and my server are on two separate machines. The web app can be used by several devices at the same time (on the same network). And the web app sends data to the server, not the other way around. I need a server that listens to every message it could intercept and process them.

Comment: @pcalkins: I took a quick look at GZipStream, but I don't quite understand. 
Do I have to gzip my data (on the web app that uses JS) before I can un-gzip it?

Comment: I think IIS would compress it by default.  Just a guess really... maybe you should include some code in your post so we can understand better what you are doing.

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for your help, I didn't know about gzip compression. I'll look into it. I have also updated the original post with some code.

Comment: I'm no expert on TCP.  Seems like you're trying to parse some values from a web request at the TCP level and things are getting confused.... probably mixed encoding types... or even transfer types?? Seems like a web request, but processed as socket?? Maybe even something about the bytes are getting mis-translated.  (ip4/ip6?)  Still not sure why you wouldn't process a web request as a web request.

Comment: More towards your questions about SSL here, you are not making an HTTPS request, so that doesn't seem like it'd be an issue....  though not real sure if the Ajax request is coming from the client... or is that a sort of in-between client?

Comment: I think you should use the same certificate. Because decryption of encrypted data requires the private key in the server certificate. Otherwise the data cannot be unpacked.

Comment: @pcalkins: Regarding what you said about web requests, I tried using an HttpListener but the result is the same. It works when the Ajax request is made from HTTP and stops working when coming from HTTPS. That's why I immediately blamed the SSL certificate... To answer your question, yes the Ajax call is made from the client (the web application that uses https).

Comment: @Bruce Zhang: That's what I think too, I'll do some research to implement that.

Comment: I guess the question is are you running a client-side proxy, or a server-side reverse proxy?  (I suppose in either case you would be the one doing the handshake... but server-side you'd need to install the site's certificate.)

Comment: So client-side seems like you'd be making 2 handshakes... one with the client, then another with the server.  For the first, you'd need some sort of cert there...

Comment: @pcalkins : I have tried to do this with SslStream using a self signed certificate, but I run into a lot of other problems. Also, my networking skills are very basic... One thing I forgot to mention is that my web app is actually a PWA, I don't know if that makes a difference. It doesn't seem to be as easy as I thought it would be. So I decided to proceed in a different way by using winforms, that should be enough for my project. Thank you very much for your help and your time!